# Oracle : SQL replace a value in a column if override exists

Tags: sql, oracle

I have table like below :

```
PRODUCT     COLLECTION_DATE      DATA      OVERRIDE
-------     ---------------      ----      --------
Laptop      2014/11/01           62          
Laptop      2014/12/01           62        75
Laptop      2015/01/01           62        
Laptop      2015/02/01           62        
Laptop      2015/03/01           62        83
Laptop      2015/04/01           62          
Laptop      2015/05/01           62
Laptop      2015/06/01           62
```

I need to override the values in `DATA` column with the values from `OVERRIDE` column to produce below data

```
PRODUCT     COLLECTION_DATE      DATA      OVERRIDE
-------     ---------------      ----      --------
Laptop      2014/11/01           62          
Laptop      2014/12/01           75        75
Laptop      2015/01/01           75        
Laptop      2015/02/01           75        
Laptop      2015/03/01           83        83
Laptop      2015/04/01           83          
Laptop      2015/05/01           83
Laptop      2015/06/01           83
```

How can I do that in SQL? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this in a single row using `coalesce()`:

```
select product, collection_date, coalesce(override, data) as data, override
from table t;
```

You seem to want the most recent non-NULL value.  In Oracle 11+, you can use the `ignore null` option on `lag()`:

```
select product, collection_date, 
       coalesce(lag(override ignore null) over (partition by product order by collection_date), data) as data,
       override
from table t;
```

If you are using an earlier version of Oracle, and `override` is always positive, you can take the cumulative sum to define groups with the same value.  Then use this for the value:

```
select product, collection_date,
       coalesce(max(override) over (partition by product, grp order by collection_date), data) as data,
       override
from (select t.*, sum(override) over (partition by product order by collection_date) as grp
      from table t
     ) t;
```

Comment: is there any way to do it in Oracle 10g?